# Access Node file on public script file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to integrate the Database I created using Node, Express and Sequelize in my script for the HTML page so that I can retrieve information and display on the page, but I can't access the file somehow using require.

This is my db.js file

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var sequelize;

if (env === 'production') {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
        dialect: 'postgres'
    });
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: __dirname + '/data/mdo.sqlite'
    });
}

var db = {};

db.testing = 'hi im here';

db.food = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/food.js');
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I tried using

```
var db = require('../../db.js');
```

But the console prints out that require is undefined, how can I use that db file on the script and for example, display all the items on my database on a list?

Thank you, if more information is needed please let me know!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered I'll leave what I did so that maybe it helps someone in the future.

Wrote a GET request on my server.js file and used an AJAX request to fetch the data and populate my HTML with append.